# My motherboard has a 4 pin connector, but my motherboard has a 24-pin power connector. Is there anyway I can connect it to the motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

So I have a pre-built HP Prodesk pc, and I wanted to upgrade it, but it required me to get a bigger wattage PSU, so I went for this - https://www.ebuyer.com/856008-thermaltake-litepower-450w-psu-ps-ltp-0450npcn-uk-2?mkwid=s_dc&pcrid=51482424299&pkw=&pmt=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwoqDtBRD-ARIsAL4pviCGyh6H_EyxLjuHYrjG0Kj_VJfkOIeNce5wp-WEIbjaDf07QDptIvIaAk9LEALw_wcB.

Is there anyway I can power my motherboard with this PSU, as my motherboard only has a 4-Pin power connector? Can I just connect the +4 part of the 20+4, or will that fry the damn thing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can power my motherboard with this PSU, as my motherboard only has a 4-Pin power connector?

The power supply you purchased is not compatible with your HP Prodesk motherboard.

> Can I just connect the +4 part of the 20+4

You cannot connect just the 4-Pin connector from your new PSU.  The PSU is not compatible with your motherboard.